# How to union the results of the select in while?

Tags: mysql

my table person like:

```
id, bron_year, file_date
2, 1943, 2010
5, 1952, 2017
7, 1953, 2018
8, 1952, 2018
9, 1954, 2017
```

Here the file_date means the file of person's create date, and file_date >= 2009.

And I create a procedure like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `aged_person`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE c_year int;
  SET c_year = 2009;
  WHILE c_year < YEAR(CURDATE()) DO
    SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE YEAR(`file_date`) = c_year AND c_year - `bron_year` >= 65 ORDER BY `file_date` ASC, `id` ASC;
    SET c_year = c_year + 1;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

It means in every year, collect the aged person (in that year, person's age >= 65).

Now I want union all the results, and must keep the order. How to do that please?

BTW, I do not want create a temp table, because some person will be out (moving house, missing visit), then the person will not in table.

Example:
If c_year = 2018, the results (keep order):

```
2, 1943, 2010
5, 1952, 2017
8, 1952, 2018
7, 1953, 2018
```

If c_year = 2019, the results (keep order):

```
2, 1943, 2010
5, 1952, 2017
8, 1952, 2018
7, 1953, 2018
9, 1954, 2017
```

Comment: Not sure why you're doing all that (which won't work). Why aren't you just doing a simple SELECT? You don't need a temp table, just a very simple SELECT statement. For the data you posted, it returns two rows (IDs 2 and 8, ages 67 and 66).

Comment: Because I must keep the order, if the year is 2018, id=7 will be the No. 4. if year is 2019, I must keep id = 7 at No. 4.

Comment: As you are ordering by file_date, this will already happen.

Comment: An ORDER BY will keep the order. I think you've vastly over-complicated the task.

Answer (score 0):

Simple query, and no stored procedures:

```
SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE file_date >= 2009 
  AND (file_date - bron_year) >= 65
ORDER BY file_date ASC, id ASC
```

Comment: Thank you. as the datas, I want get the order as:
 2, 1943, 2010
 5, 1952, 2017
 8, 1952, 2018
 7, 1953, 2018
 9, 1954, 2017